# Decompiling the class which have nested class in it

Tags: java

I am trying to see source code of a library. I extracted the library  and it gave me all the class files.

I am trying to Decompile a particular class which have nested class in it.

I have class file for both for example XYZ.class and XYZ$1.class. Is there anyway I can Decompile both of them at once and get a single Java file.

Any help on this is so much appreciated.

I used JD-GUI. It doesn't show the source code for Inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extracted the library manually using below comment in command prompt

```
jar xf myFile.jar
```

I opened the extracted folder in JD-GUI, it gave me the decompiled version of both main and inner class in single file.

Note: Earlier I opened library directly in JD-GUI in that case it didn't show me inner class at all.

Comment: @AnkurKumawat It decompiled inner classes or nested classes